# How to specify how lossy/lossless a .webm conversion will be (in ffmpeg)?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, lossless-compression, lossy-compression

I can't seem to understand how to make the conversion lossless (or at least visually lossless)? The outputs have some fast moving parts at times, and the output would become blocky; I would like to keep it as lossless as possible, while still maintaining some compression. What would I have to tweak at the command line? Thanks you~

`ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i in.webm -c:v libvpx -vf scale=400:416,hue=h=45:s=1 -auto-alt-ref 0 out.webm`

Comment: You're encoding with libvpx which outputs VP8. Is this what you want, or do you prefer VP9?

Comment: I'm guessing I prefer VP9 since it's newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [FFmpeg Wiki: VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9), "two-pass is the recommended encoding method for libvpx-vp9 as some quality-enhancing encoder features are only available in 2-pass mode". Example of your command:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i in.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -vf scale=400:416,hue=h=45:s=1 -b:v 0 -crf 30 -pass 1 -an -f null /dev/null
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i in.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -vf scale=400:416,hue=h=45:s=1 -b:v 0 -crf 30 -pass 2 -c:a copy output.webm
```

The CRF value can be from 0–63. Lower values mean better quality. Recommended values range from 15–35, with 31 being recommended for 1080p HD video. For more info see [Google - Getting Started with VP9](https://developers.google.com/media/vp9/get-started).